# Batch Export Symbols to PNG - Illustrator

Tags: javascript, png, batch-processing, symbols, adobe-illustrator

I was originally going to post this at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/, but since it's a code question it seems more appropriate here.

I want to export all the symbols in an open Illustrator document to **seperate** pngs.

The following javascript (.jsx) script is really close, but the pngs being exported are empty, which tells me there's still something substantial missing.

What could the missing element be?

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;  
var symbolCount = doc.symbols.length;  

$.writeln(symbolCount + " symbols"); // log symbol count

for(var i = 0; i < doc.symbols.length; i++) {
    $.writeln(doc.symbols[i].name); // log symbol names

   var dir = doc.path; // save to document's folder
   dir.changePath(doc.symbols[i].name + '.png');
   savePNG(dir);
}

// Save PNG file

function savePNG(file) {
   // export SAVE-FOR-WEB options
   var exp = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
   exp.transparency = true;

   // export as SAVE-FOR-WEB
   doc.exportFile(file, ExportType.PNG24, exp);
}
```

PS. Here's a link for the Illustrator scripting documentation:
http://adobe.ly/1JxLlUK

Comment: Also a good point to know is that this script was adopted from an "export layers to png" script, so some of it, `savePNG()` mainly, might still be related to layers

Comment: Shouldn't you really have put up this edit as a new question?

Comment: I've moved part 2 of this question to a new question: [Batch Export Symbols to SVG - Illustrator](http://bit.ly/1eG9hIE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else needing this, here's what I turned the script into:

Thanks to **Jongware** for the help.

```
/*
 * Export Symbols as PNGs - Illustrator
 * --------------------------------------
 * Created By Shane Parsons - 30PT Design Inc.
 * http://30ptdesign.com/
 */

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var symbolCount = doc.symbols.length;

if (symbolCount >= 1) {

    if (confirm("Are all your layers hidden?")) {

        // choose directory
        var dest = Folder(doc.path).selectDlg();

        // folder chosen
        if (dest) {

            // create temp layer
            doc.layers.add();

            // loop through symbols
            for (var i = 0; i < doc.symbols.length; i++) {

                // place a symbol instance - temp
                var symbol = doc.symbolItems.add(doc.symbols[i]);

                // assign name
                var filename = (doc.symbols[i].name)

                // export symbols
                savePNG(dest, filename);

                // delete temp symbol instance
                symbol.remove();
            }
            // remove temp layer
            doc.layers[0].remove();
        }
    }

    function savePNG(dest, filename) {
        // save options
        var type = ExportType.PNG24;
        var options = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
        options.transparency = true;

        // file
        var file = new File(dest + "/" + filename);

        // export
        doc.exportFile(file, type, options);
    }

} else {
    alert("You don't have any symbols in this document");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**@shane**

This is a truly wonderful script, thanks for making it! I built upon it to fit my workflow. One thing that I noticed is that the exported PNGs does not have the same dimension as the graphics inside the symbol. Below is a zoomed in screenshot of the image export;

[since I'm not allowed to post images yet, here's a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwZce.png)

The 83x83px vector rectangle was exported as 84x83px PNG

I corrected this by placing the symbol at 0,0 reference of the document

```js
// place a symbol instance - temp
var symbol = doc.symbolItems.add(doc.symbols[i]);
    symbol.top = 0;
    symbol.left = 0;
```

Then let the code run it's course. I'm not a programmer myself, but it works on my end.

Answer (score 1):

`doc.exportFile` does what you tell it to – so it exports a PNG of your *document*.

To export the symbols, place each of them one by one into your document, export the entire thing as a PNG (note here that any contents of the document itself will be exported as well!), then delete the symbol instance again.

It takes only a minor addition to your `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < doc.symbols.length; i++) {
    $.writeln(doc.symbols[i].name); // log symbol names

    s = doc.symbolItems.add(doc.symbols[i]); // place a Symbol instance

   var dir = doc.path; // save to document's folder
   dir.changePath(doc.symbols[i].name + '.png');
   savePNG(dir);
   s.remove();  // .. and delete it here
}
```

This results in the following list of files for my default set of Symbols:

[image: symbols png list]